# How to scrape website protected area using Win HTTtrack

Tags: windows, website, screen-scraping

I need to scrape information from a website that will need to be logged in to see all the data I need. I was trying using puppeteer but I've noticed that it will be not able to login so I've done a search and now I'm using WinHTTrack to download the whole website. My main question is, how I can access to the restricted area using this tool so I will be able to download all the needed informations?

For other websites I was using web scraper chrome extension but seems not working on this old website that is running without https TLS connection.

Thank you for the suggestions.